# How to extracts files that are in folder within a ZIP file with Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, zip, inno-setup

Well, what I have is a Python project, and now am creating an installer.
I added to that the project's file .exe and a .zip file.
The **zip** file contains .exe modules, data, etc. And its structure is like this:

```
example.zip:
|---project-folder:
    |----here will be the files.
    |----here will be the files.
```

What I want is to extract those files that are inside the `project-folder`. So the .exe can run.
I have this code to extract a zip file:

```pascal
[Code]
    
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ForceDirectories(ExpandConstant('{localappdata}\folder-A\app\folder-B'))
end;

const
  SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX = 4;
  SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL = 16;

procedure unzip(ZipFile, TargetFldr: variant);
var
 shellobj: variant;
 SrcFldr, DestFldr: variant;
 shellfldritems: variant;
begin
  if FileExists(ZipFile) then begin
    if not DirExists(TargetFldr) then 
      if not ForceDirectories(TargetFldr) then begin
        MsgBox('Can not create folder '+TargetFldr+' !!', mbError, MB_OK);
        Exit;
      end;    

  shellobj := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
  SrcFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(ZipFile);
  DestFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(TargetFldr);
  shellfldritems := SrcFldr.Items;
  DestFldr.CopyHere(
    shellfldritems, SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX or SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
  begin
     unzip(ExpandConstant('{app}\example.zip'),ExpandConstant('{app}\'));
  end;
end;
```

### The results:

- `app.exe`
- `unins.bat`
- `unins.exe`
- `example.zip` (and I want this zip file to be deleted after extracting)
- `project-folder` (here I want the files inside the folders)

### What I want:

- `app.exe`
- `unins.bat`
- `unins.exe`
- files... (files that are inside the `project-folder`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer directly to the subfolder:

```pascal
SrcFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(ZipFile + '\project-folder');
```